# changing DIV visibility with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

EDIT: Since the question has became quite popular I will fix the problem so it will be working code example. The original problem is still listed, But the **code works**.

i am trying to show a div after pressing a button but this wont work, any idea why is that?

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST" align="right" id="post_form">
<input type="button" value="click me" onClick="show()">
<div id="show_button">  fdsfds </div><br>
</form>

#show_button{
 visibility:hidden;
}

function show(){
  // alert("cheked the button - worked");
  document.getElementById("show_button").style.visibility= 'visible' ;
}
```

Comment: You should wrap the id with quotes: `document.getElementById("show_button")`

Comment: @Antony you are so right my friend, to much time wasted... thanks alot god bless you.

Answer (score 20):

Change your CSS to:

```
#show_button{
 display: none
}
```

And you in your javascript:

```
function show(){
  //alert("cheked the button - worked");
  document.getElementById('show_button').style.display= 'block' ;
}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, I missed that, however, I corrected my answer for further reference

Answer (score 4):

Typo error change it  `document.getElementById(show_button)` to  `document.getElementById("show_button")`

```
function show(){
  document.getElementById("show_button").style.visibility= "visible" ;
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer? Perhaps explain what this will do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function show(){
  //alert("cheked the button - worked");
  document.getElementById("show_button").style.visibility= "visible" ;
}
```

or

```
function show(){
  //alert("cheked the button - worked");
  document.getElementById(show_button).style.display= "inline" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById(show_button)` -: syntax error, Missing quotes " " !

Comment: I didn't try that in any editor. Anyhow, I use dreamweaver cs 6.